# Boundary condition optimization (variation problem)

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, boundary-value-problem

There is a axial symetric region $z>0$, $z<a$, $r<R(z)$. There is a some system of differential equation (In my problem it is a Maxwell's equations) $L_i f=0$.

I need to find a function $R(z)$ (which define above) for such the solution of this  system of differential equation $f(r,z,\phi)$ with this boundary condition

$$z>0,\quad z<a, \quad\text{and}\quad r<R(z)$$

maximaze the following integral
$$
\int_0^a f^2 dz
$$

It looks like the variation problem but with boundary condition variation. But I can not find nothing similiar  in books. I gues this type problem a very common and should be solved if it posible. I will be heppy for to the useful idea or links.

Comment: What is the variable, $R$ and $R$ alone (not also $a$)?

Comment: Function $R=R(z)$ should be found. $a$ is  a fixed constant.

Comment: What happens to the $z$ and $\phi$ variables in the integration?

Comment: The equation that you are solving is linear, so if $f$ is a solution, so is $2 f$, $3 f$, etc. So your integral can be arbitrarily large.